# install g77 using fink

Tags: fink

I am trying to install convex optimization package OBOE:
https://projects.coin-or.org/OBOE/wiki/MacosxOboe

I followed its instruction, but I run into errors in this step:

```
fink install g77
```

I think fink is properly install because:

```
fink install atlas
```

is run successfully;

while

```
fink install g77
```

tells me:

```
Information about 10346 packages read in 1 seconds.
Failed: no package found for specification 'g77'!
```

does someone know what happened? Thank you

Comment: error message is that fink does not have a package called g77 - why do you think it should have?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27092293/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1):

Check out question 5.8 in http://www.finkproject.org/faq/usage-fink.php?phpLang=en#unstable I got the hint from http://sourceforge.net/p/fink/mailman/message/25799171/

> Q5.8: There's this package in unstable that I want to install, but the
>   fink command just says 'no package found'. How can I install it?
>
> A: First make sure you understand what 'unstable' means. Packages in
>   the unstable tree are not in stable for any number of reasons. It
>   could be because there are known issues, validation errors, or just
>   not enough people giving feedback that the package works for them. For
>   that reason, Fink doesn't search the unstable tree by default.
>
> If you do enable unstable, please remember to e-mail the maintainer if
>   something works (or even if it doesn't). Feedback from users like you
>   is what we use to determine if something is ready for stable! To find
>   out the maintainer of a package, run fink info packagename.
>
> For fink-0.26 and later: If you run fink configure one of the
>   questions will ask whether you want to turn the unstable trees on.
>
> To configure Fink to use unstable when you have an earlier version of
>   the fink tool than 0.26, edit /sw/etc/fink.conf, and add unstable/main
>   and unstable/crypto to the Trees: line.
>
> If you use Fink Commander, then there is a Preference to use unstable
>   packages.
>
> None of these options actually download the unstable tree's package
>   descriptions.You'll need to turn on rsync or cvs updating to do this,
>   which is not set up by default on a new Fink installation. The
>   following command sequence will set you up on a new Fink installation:

```
fink selfupdate
```

followed by

```
fink selfupdate-rsync
```

or

```
fink selfupdate-cvs
```

and then

```
fink index -f
fink scanpackages
```

> Note: There are Fink Commander analogs
>   for everything except fink index -f. You will have to use the command
>   line for that.
>
> If you're already set up with rsync or cvs updating, then the
>   following command sequence (or the Fink Commander analogs) will
>   suffice:
>
> fink selfupdate fink index fink scanpackages   If you're not sure what
>   your update method is, check fink --version in at a command line and
>   see if that mentions cvs or rsync.
>
> If you don't want to install any more from unstable than your specific
>   package(s) and its (their) dependencies, (and any base packages that
>   got updated) don't use the update-all command until you turn the
>   unstable tree back off.